# Google Calendar Push Notification Channel subscription Creation

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have to create calendar push notification but didn't undersatnd how to create channel subscription ?

```
 private void perormWatch(Calendar service, String user) throws Exception {
            Channel content = new Channel();
            content.setId("abcd@gmail.com");
            content.setType("web_hook");
            content.setAddress("http://localhost:8888/calendarNotiication");
            com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.CalendarList.Watch cal = service.calendarList().watch(content);
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to set up a channel with [`CalendarList.watch()`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendarList/watch). To do so you must satisfy three minimum requirements:

- An `id` that uniquely identifies this new channel within your project.
- The type property set on `web_hook`
- An `address` over HTTPS where you want to receive the notifications.

By keeping that in mind, you only have to update your script to match the requirements. First of all the `address` is set to an invalid URL in the example. It must start with `https`, not `http`. Please be aware that only valid SSL certificates are acceptable (i.e. not selfsigned certificates, revoked or badly formed). Also please check that the `id` is truly unique within your project. Those small modifications should suffice in the example code, but feel free to update your question and leave a comment if you need further solutions.